# What is the difference between an isolated and a closed system?

Tags: energy-conservation, terminology

What is the difference between difference between an [isolated system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_system) and a [closed system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_system)?

Is it that for an isolated system, the system is free from external effects,
but for closed system, the system can be subjected by external effects , but are unaffected by it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In thermodynamics, a closed system is a system which cannot exchange matter with the environment. An isolated system cannot exchange matter nor energy with the environment. So, an isolated system is also closed, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: In other words, in thermodynamics terminology a closed system would be described by the $canonical$ ensemble and an isolated system by the $microcanonical$ ensemble.